# cloud-init/cloud-config syntax documentation

Tags: 13.04, server, cloud-init

I am looking for cloud-init/cloud-config syntax documentation. I have been through https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit
I need to know what all namespace are supported by cloud-init. e.g. "`byobu_by_default`" is a valid resource where as "`This_is_great`" is not a valid resource.

I did extensive googling but could not find any documentation Also I had been through the “examples” directory and it was helpful but I wanted above said documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been searching for a while now, and was disappointed to see no answers to your question.  Here are the best I've found so far, one of which you mentioned:

- http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/examples.html
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit

You can override anything in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`, too, so that can be a useful example.

**Edit:** [This is probably the example](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cloud-init-dev/cloud-init/trunk/view/head:/doc/examples/cloud-config.txt) you were talking about.  According to multiple sources, it should be mostly complete.  [Here's the full list](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cloud-init-dev/cloud-init/trunk/files/891/doc/examples) for anyone else who hasn't found them yet.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer I added another link.  I think you've already seen that file, but it's allegedly the most complete documentation that exists at this time.

Comment: oh yes, the launchpad one. Anyway, you have summed up all possible Cloud-init docs in one place. This should be really helpful for any one looking for Cloud-init documentation. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Also, please note that doc is installed in /usr/share/doc/cloud-init for the exact version that your system has installed.  This way you can find documentation specific to that version.  Looking at trunk you might see new features that do not exist in your version.